# xcode error when compiling build failed

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I'm doing an app using firebase, I've already done the set up with pod and today when I re-opened the project after a bit of time I have this problem in the picture, any help on how to fix it?

I've already tried to clean and deleting pod files and re-executing a "pod install" but it seems he can no longer see my "import Firebase"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there could be a number of reasons for your error. Here are a couple easily overlooked steps when installing Firebase with cocoapods:

1. The top of your pod file likely looks similar to the snippet below. It appears you're using swift so make sure you uncomment the "use_frameworks!" line as I've done here :

   ```
   # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
   # platform :ios, '10.0'
   # Uncomment this line if you're using Swift 
   use_frameworks!
   ```
2. Make sure from now on you open your project from the terminal:

   ```
   $ open your-project.xcworkspace
   ```
3. If you still don't have any luck it may be worth carefully reviewing the getting started guide for Firebase: [Add Firebase to your iOS Project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup)

Comment: Yeah the podfile is just like you wrote it. at this point i think i'll have to create a new project and copy n paste in it the source code and then creating again the entire storyboard.

Comment: Before you recreate your whole project you could check your cocoapods version, if its too old you could have problems with the libraries it installs. You can check your current version with: `pod --version`. I think they just released a 1.3.0 beta version, but you should be fine if you have at least version 1.1.1. And did you make sure to open your project from the terminal with: `open project-name.xcworkspace`? If you open your project with the .xcodeproj extension the Firebase libraries won't be available.

Comment: i have 1.2.1 and yeah i opened the project via terminal

Comment: One other thing I had to do in my project was explicitly add Firebase to the header search paths. I did this by clicking on my project in the navigator, Then selected my app under "Targets", then I went to Build Settings, and searched for "Header Search Paths", and under there I added the path to the Firebase.h file in my pods directory. I did this with the following string: `"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/Firebase"` I also had to create a bridging header file (just a header file with this line in it `#import <Firebase.h`), but I didn't think there was any need for those anymore...